# Why does Scheme allow mutation to closed environment in a closure?

Tags: scheme

The following Scheme code

```
(let ((x 1))
   (define (f y) (+ x y))
   (set! x 2)
   (f 3) )
```

which evaluates to 5 instead of 4. It is surprising considering Scheme promotes static scoping. Allowing subsequent mutation to affect bindings in the closed environment in a closure seems to revert to kinda dynamic scoping. Any specific reason that it is allowed?

EDIT:

I realized the code above is less obvious to reveal the problem I am concerned.  I put another code fragment below:

```
(define x 1)

(define (f y) (+ x y))

(set! x 2)

(f 3)  ; evaluates to 5 instead of 4
```

Comment: I made the change to make it less tangled with local scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing such mutation is *excellent*. It allows you to define objects with internal state, accessible only through pre-arranged means:

```
(define (adder n)
  (let ((x n))    
    (lambda (y)
      (cond ((pair? y) (set! x (car y)))
            (else (+ x y))))))

(define f (adder 1))
(f 5)                 ; 6
(f (list 10))
(f 5)                 ; 15
```

There is no way to change that `x` except through the `f` function and its established protocols - precisely because of *lexical* scoping in Scheme.

The `x` variable refers to a memory cell in the internal environment frame belonging to that `let` *in which* the internal `lambda` is defined - thus returning the combination of `lambda` and its defining environment, otherwise known as "closure".

And if you do not provide the protocols for mutating this internal variable, nothing can change it, as it is *internal* and we've long left the defining scope:

```
(set! x 5) ; WRONG: "x", what "x"? it's inaccessible!
```

---

EDIT: your new code, which changes the meaning of your question completely, there's no problem there as well. It is like we are still inside that defining environment, so naturally the internal variable is still accessible.

More problematic is the following

```
(define x 1)
(define (f y) (+ x y))
(define x 4)
(f 5) ;?? it's 9.
```

I would expect the second define to not interfere with the first, but [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.1)  says `define` is like `set!` in the top-level.

Closures package their defining environments with them. **Top-level environment is always accessible.**

The variable `x` that `f` refers to, lives in the top-level environment, and hence is accessible from any code in the same scope. That is to say, *any* code.

Comment: I agree this simulating-object feature is plausible.  But note that `set!` in your example appears inside `f`.  Naturally it can mutate `x`.  `(set! x 5)` here would fail but because `x` is a variable local to `adder`, that is, it is not in scope.  I have updated the code fragment in my question.  You can see that `set!` appears outside `f` but can still mutate a variable that is closed in the closure for `f`.  It is this use case I am against.  I think it is possible still to support the feature you exemplified and disallowing `set!` to variables closed in a closure from outside the closure.

Comment: I think my argument against this mutating a variable closed in a closure _outside_ the closure (you note my previous comment) remains, regardless of top-level.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, :)  Regarding your new EDIT, how about putting the first two definitions in a file, load it, and then setting or redefine `x`, and then evaluate `(f 5)`.  Would you say that we are still inside the definition environment?

Comment: the top level in a file may also behave that way; the point is, *closure* packages lambda with its definitional environment, and the top level is always accessible, so such closures are always "open". Yes, in file the second define acts like set!, just as in REPL. I'm using MIT Scheme - don't know if it's implementation dependent. I'd expect the second `x` not to affect the 1st.

Comment: But you have seen that in the first piece of code, even the closed environment is not the always-accesible top-level environment, you can still mutate a variable closed in a closure from outside the closure.  That is why I think whether the closed environment is the top-level is irrelevant here.

Comment: in the first code what's closed over is (the TLE, extended by `let`). And the let-introduced part of environment is inaccessible - except through the `f` function, because it was defined that way. But not in any other way.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and all discussions spread here and there, Will.  I think now I get it.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ideas you are confusing here: scoping and indirection through memory. Lexical scope guarantees you that the reference to `x` always points to the binding of `x` in the `let` binding.

This is not violated in your example. Conceptually, the `let` binding is actually creating a new location in memory (containing `1`) and *that location* is the value bound to `x`. When the location is dereferenced, the program looks up the current value at that memory location. When you use `set!`, it sets the value in memory. Only parties that have access to the location bound to `x` (via lexical scope) can access or mutate the contents in memory.

In contrast, dynamic scope allows any code to change the value you're referring to in `f`, regardless of whether you gave access to the location bound to `x`. For example,

```
(define f
  (let ([x 1])
    (define (f y) (+ x y))
    (set! x 2)
    f))

(let ([x 3]) (f 3))
```

would return `6` in an imaginary Scheme with dynamic scope.

Comment: You are right.  It is not dynamic scoping (I said "kinda", maybe I should have said "seeming" ;)  My concern here is whether allowing such behavior is good or not.  At least I could not see any positive consequence.  Imaging you define a function `f` in which a global variable `x` is used.  Later you `set!` `x` and call `f`, it explodes.  It seems to me when creating a closure only closing environment but not store is a bad design choice.

Comment: Okay, I think I better understand your question now. Closing over the store has other issues: how do you determine how much of the store to close over? With the environment, it's obvious from the text of the program: only the references in scope. With the store, if `f` calls `g`, does `f` have to close over the memory locations accessed by `g`? Also, how would that affect programs that concurrently use the same memory locations you closed over?

Comment: I think `f` does not have to close the store accessible by `g` even if `f` calls `g`, since `g` have already closed it.  I have not thought about the possible consequence involving concurrency yet.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not dynamic scoping. Note that your `define` here is an internal definition, accessible only to the code inside the `let`. In specific, `f` is not defined at the module level. So nothing has leaked out.

Internal definitions are internally implemented as `letrec` (R5RS) or `letrec*` (R6RS). So, it's treated the same (if using R6RS semantics) as:

```
(let ((x 1))
  (letrec* ((f (lambda (y) (+ x y))))
    (set! x 2)
    (f 3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is obvious, but I don't think that anyone else has touched upon it, so let me say it: *yes, it's scary*. What you're really observing here is that mutation makes it very hard to reason about what your program is going to do. Purely functional code--code with no mutation--always produces the same result when called with the same inputs.  Code with state and mutation does not have this property. It may be that calling a function twice with the same inputs will produce separate results.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, John, :).  But here I am particularly interested in the problem mutation could cause and how to restrict the trouble it could make.

Comment: no, the OP is just wrong in their claim that the variable inside closure can be mutated from the outside. It can't, the variable in question is in top level scope, and *everything* is *inside* top-level scope. The question is not about merits of stateful vs pure functional programming; it is specific.

Comment: @plmday the Scheme way of restricting "mutation troubles" is to introduce new scope and to close over a variable in that *new* scope, to prevent any *"outside"* access to it - while allowing the authorized access from inside *the same* scope (or any "child" scope).

Comment: @WillNess: You are right, saying that variables inside a closure can be mutated from outside the closure is wrong.  But allowing later mutation to those variables always living in the top level can still affect the behavior of an already defined function is wrong.  How do you think about my suggestion elsewhere on this page that when creating a closure for a function, also close or freeze the store?

Comment: @plmday let's talk implementation: do you want to duplicate the representations of all store values referred to by the closure? You might be able to do something like that, but I think that for most people, it's simpler just to use immutable data or to ensure that there are no external references to the mutable ones.

Comment: @plmday just don't define them that way, that's all. Define them inside child environments - extended by `let` (as shown in my answer, with `adder`, or as `(define f (let ((x ...)) (lambda ... x ...)))` ) - and all will be OK. Define them with references to top-level variables only if you *really* need that kind of behaviour (which is, almost never). That's all. IOW, this is a non-issue. :)